# How to put result of soql query in map<Id,String>

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have created a trigger in Salesforce and i am fetching the result by soql query and store the result in a map, but it show the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid initializer type List found for
>   Map: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a
>   valid SObject List at line 7 column 25

```
trigger insertUpdateOwnerToSalesRep on Account (after insert, before update) {
    if (trigger.IsAfter && trigger.IsUpdate) {
        List<User> lstUser =[select id,name from User where Id in:(Trigger.NewMap).keySet()];

        //Map<Id,String> ac=new Map<Id,String>([]);
        Map<ID, String> m = new Map<ID, String>([select id,name from User where Id in:(Trigger.NewMap).keySet()]);
        for(Account ac:Trigger.New) {
            System.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\t'+ac.ownerid);
            if (ac.owner!=null) {
                User user=ac.owner;
                System.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\t'+user);
                //ac.Sales_Rep__c=ac.owner.userName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You try to select users by Id, but when you call Trigger.NewMap.keySet(), you will get set of account Ids, not user (because trigger on account object). Possibly, you want to get all users related to account, so use AccountId in 'where' condition. Also I'd like to note, that you don't use 'lstUser' variable after getting.

As for getting Map from select, you should use `Map<Id, User>` instead of `Map<Id, String>`:

```
Map<Id, User> m = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User where AccountId in :(Trigger.NewMap).keySet()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working fine as compile time error removed.